# Delete string match from another file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

i have 1.txt:

```
hi aa my name is bb tom
how are you cc today
```

and i have 2.txt ( the word that i dont want )

```
aa
bb
cc
```

and my expected output is

```
hi my name is tom
how are you today
```

what i have tried so far is

```
sed -e "s/$(sed 's:/:\\/:g' 2.txt)/ /" 
or
grep -Fvf 2.txt 1.txt
```

i have more than 100 words that i dont want, so i have to put it in one sentence, thanks

Comment: If `1.txt` includes the word "aardvark", would you expect to see "rdvark" in the output? Or do you only want to consider whole-word matches?

Comment: yea, i would love to keep aardvark, so i think i am going to edit my 2.txt to a standard format like " aa " . any thought on deleting them all ? thanks!

Comment: The problem with a format like `" aa "` is that it won't match lines that start with `"aa "` or end with `" aa"`.

Comment: yea, that is a big problem, but that is as far as i can think of, any help?

Comment: Define a "word". For example is `there's` a word or is that 2 words? If `there's` appears in 1.txt and `there` in 2.txt would the output be `'s` (i.e. `there` removed from the string `there's`) or something else? Is there anything other than space-separated strings of letters in either file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without normalizing spaces...

```
$ sed -f <(sed 's/.*/s_\\b&\\b__g/' remove_list) file

hi  my name is  tom
how are you  today
aardwark
```

to handle spaces and word boundaries, one alternative

```
$ sed -f <(sed 's/.*/s_ &\\b__g;s_\\b& __g;s_\\b&\\b__g/' remove) file
```

however, at this point it's better to switch to `awk`

Comment: hi, i have tried both, but the output is just same as 1.txt . i am using mac, is it a problem?

Comment: yea, i use sed a lot, but many times different system use different flag, and i am still learning. can you tel me what kind of system u using?

Comment: this is with GNU sed, `\b` for word boundary should be standard, not using any extensions as far as I know.

Comment: Mac OS sed doesn't like `\b` for some reason.  But this seems to work: `sed -f <(sed 's/.*/s_[[:<:]]&[[:>:]]__g/' file2.txt) file1.txt`

Comment: hi jas, it works. any website can you recommand me to master it?

Answer (score 0):

***gawk*** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$0]; next }{ for(i in a) gsub("\\<"i"\\> *","",$0) }1' 2.txt 1.txt
```

The output:

```
hi my name is tom
how are you today
```

---

- `a[$0]` - accumulating words which should be removed from each sentence
- `gsub("\\<"i"\\> *","",$0)` - replacing each "unwanted" word (as a whole word) with empty string

Comment: will leave a space if the removed word is at the end of line.  may not be important though.

Comment: may i know what kind of system are you using? i am using mac. would it make a different?

Comment: @RobertChoy, run `brew install gawk` and then, apply my approach